# Function signature error (Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I get error after update XCode to 6.3 `Function signature '(TimeInterval) -> ()' is not compatible with expected type '(value: TimeInterval) -> ()'`.

Code is following:

```
//in `editView` property signature
var changeAction: ((value: TimeInterval)->())?

//usage
editView?.changeAction = { [unowned self] (newValue: EditDateView.TimeInterval) in
    self.presentTime = newValue
    wPopup?.dismiss(true)
}
```

#### Edit:

I found one solution for this:

```
@IBAction func timePressed() {
    // some code
    weak var wPopup = popup
    func timeChanged(#value: EditDateView.TimeInterval) {
        self.presentTime = value
        wPopup?.dismiss(true)
    }
    editView?.changeAction = timeChanged
}
```

Or:

```
@IBAction func timePressed() {
    // some code
    weak var wPopup = popup
    editView?.changeAction = timeChanged(wPopup)
}

func timeChanged(wPopup: KLCPopup?)(value: EditDateView.TimeInterval) {
    self.presentTime = value
    wPopup?.dismiss(true)
}
```

But this may handle self reference, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be confusing the type of the closure's parameter with the argument supplied to the closure upon call. It look like this assuming that `TimeInterval` is a valid type.

```
editView?.changeAction = { [unowned self] (newValue: TimeInterval) in
    self.presentTime = newValue
    wPopup?.dismiss(true)
}
```

Which you would call like this, assuming that `EditDateView.TimeInterval` is a valid instance of the `TimeInterval` type.

```
editView?.changeAction?(value: EditDateView.TimeInterval)
```

Comment: With call no problem. I can't setup property with this closure cause compiler something don't like in definition.