# Fight with "Function signature '' is not compatible with expected type ''" in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, closures

I get message: `Function signature '(StatusUpload) -> ()' is not compatible with expected type '(status: StatusUpload) -> ()'`. What I'm doing wrong.

```
typealias StatusUpload = (fileNum: Int, totalFilesCount: Int, fileBytesUploaded: CUnsignedLongLong, fileBytesTotal: CUnsignedLongLong)

progress: ((status: StatusUpload)->())?
// ...
var newProgressClosure: ((status: StatusUpload)->())? = nil
if let progress = progress {
    newProgressClosure = {(status: StatusUpload)->() in
        var newStatus = status
        newStatus.fileNum++
        newStatus.totalFilesCount++
        progress(status: newStatus)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing `status:` from the first two declarations?

Comment: After remove `status:` everywhere all work. It's sad... Thank you. Also I find my own answer with same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638252/function-signature-error-swift-1-2 =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `status:` from the caller.

Use `progress: ((StatusUpload)->())` instead of  `progress: ((status: StatusUpload)->())`

Answer (score 0):

This builds for me.

```
    typealias StatusUpload = (fileNum: Int, totalFilesCount: Int, fileBytesUploaded: CUnsignedLongLong, fileBytesTotal: CUnsignedLongLong)
    var progress : ((status: StatusUpload)->())?
    // ...
    var newProgressClosure: ((StatusUpload)->())? = nil
    if let progress = progress {
        newProgressClosure = {(StatusUpload)->() in
            var newStatus = status
            newStatus.fileNum++
            newStatus.totalFilesCount++
            progress(status: newStatus)
        }
    }
```